# How to get value of a Nullable Type via reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

Using reflection I need to retrieve the value of a propery of a `Nullable Type of DateTime`

How can I do this?

When I try `propertyInfo.GetValue(object, null)` it does not function.

thx

My code:

```
 var propertyInfos = myClass.GetType().GetProperties();

 foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
 {
     object propertyValue= propertyInfo.GetValue(myClass, null);
 }
```

propertyValue result always null for nullable type

Comment: Does not function in what way? Saying "it doesn't work" is much less helpful than describing how it *doesn't* work.

Comment: How about posting an example code of what doesn't work? And describing what the problem is? "Doesn't function" isn't exactly the most precise description.

Comment: A short but complete program would really help...

Comment: You're still missing essential code. How your class looks like and where the value is initialized to something different from null. A program that does compile and exhibit the problem would be nice.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Reflection and `Nullable<T>` are a bit of a pain; reflection uses `object`, and `Nullable<T>` has special boxing/unboxing rules for `object`. So by the time you have an `object` it is  **no longer** a `Nullable<T>` - it is either `null` or *the value itself*.

i.e.

```
int? a = 123, b = null;
object c = a; // 123 as a boxed int
object d = b; // null
```

This makes it a bit confusing sometimes, *and* note that you can't get the original `T` from an empty `Nullable<T>` that has been boxed, as all you have is a `null`.

Comment: You can get the underlying type of the boxed nullable if it's not null with `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type)`

Answer (score 0):

Given simple class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public DateTime? Bar { get; set; }
}
```

And the code:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();

foo.Bar = DateTime.Now;

PropertyInfo pi = foo.GetType().GetProperty("Bar");

object value = pi.GetValue(foo, null);
```

value has either null (if .Bar is null) or the DateTime value.  What part of this isn't working for you?

Comment: It is.  "DateTime?" is the same thing as "Nullable<DateTime>"

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained *why* this is the case (as Marc's does)

Comment: What is not working is when we want to get the value as a Nullable<DateTime> and not a DateTime. How to have Nullable<DateTime> (or Nullable<Xxxx> for any type as we are using reflection).